# Does Git Branch create new files?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a folder with a Linked List implementation that right now caters only to integers. I have tested it, and it works perfect. Now my boss tells me that I need to update my implementation so that it can now work with any datatype.

Before I proceed to edit my code, I create a new git branch called _test_templates, switch to this new branch with git checkout, and start experimenting. After some time, I realize my code is not working and I think I will start again from scratch. I switch back to Master, and delete my _test_templates branch.

What confuses me is that the changes made to my Node.h, Node.cpp, LinkedList.h, LinkedList.cpp, and main.cpp within my _templates_test branch are present in master branch too.

Why? Wasn't I working in a totally new temporary space called a branch independent of master?

I didn't commit the changes on the new branch locally or to remote.

Comment: Did you commit the changes? Are they managed by git?

Comment: No, David, I didn't commit the changes in _templates_test branch, neither locally nor remote. Why?

Comment: They're not in your master branch. They're in your local files, which now are different from the files in the master branch because you edited them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git branch` will create a new place for commits (kind of), and a new index to add files to. However, changes to files in your working directory are not part of the branch, even if the files themselves are tracked. When you checked out your `master` branch again, you kept the working changes you had yet to commit from your `_test_templates` branch.

From a safety standpoint, this makes sense - the changes aren't committed, so git would have no way of recovering them if they were thrown away when you changed branches. They could be automatically stashed, but that isn't very user-friendly. So instead the changes are simply kept locally.

Answer (score 0):

Run `git reset --hard` to discard any non committed changes.